# how to make a row highlight in a large table using jquery

Tags: jquery

On most of tables, or anything that has lot of data rows, I have seen that when something is edited that row becomes yellow for a while and then after a while goes back to its normal state.

I have a data table with about 500 rows.  User can click edit on anything, edit that row on a new page, and come back to page with all 500 rows.  When user comes back to page with 500 rows I want to make the last edited row highlight for a while.

I know we can use addCss but how will I remove the css after a while?

can someone who has done this please suggest a way or show an example?

I am doing this but getting a JS error:

```
$('#'+test).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

where '#`'+test` is a `id` of a `tr`

Answer (score 4):

Give **[Highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)** a try. This is the same thing that happens to your answer on SO when you hit "Post Your Answer".

Suppose you have this HTML:

```
    <table id="myTbl">
        <tr>
            <td>Frist</td>
            <td>Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>Row</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTbl tr:first-child").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
}); //this is from jquery.com page.
```

Comment: highlight seems to only work on 'div'.  I am trying to make it work on 'tr' so that I can make the whole row highlight

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need [jQuery UI in order to use the highlight effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/).

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('tr').effect('highlight', 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this

```
$(window).load(function() { // that way, the transition won't start until the whole page has loaded. note I think you may only have one of these events.

    $('#my-table tr:last td').addClass('highlight');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#my-table tr:last td').animate( { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }, 1000);

    }, 3000);



});
```

Now if you set up a class highlight in your CSS, the page should should show your last table row highlighted, and it should begin to fade to normal in roughly 3 seconds.